# Let $F$ be a field and let $f(x)$ be a non constant element of $F[x]$. Then, there exists a splitting field $E$ for $f(x)$ over $F$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory

> Let $F$ be a field and let $f(x)$ be a non constant element of $F[x]$. Then, there exists a splitting field $E$ for $f(x)$ over $F$.

I have some queries regarding this theorem of existence of splitting fields.

Firstly, let $E$ be an extension field of $F$ and let $f(x) \in F[x]$. We say that $f(x)$ splits in $E$ if $f(x)$ can be factored as a product of linear factors in $E[x]$.

> We call $E$ a splitting field for $f(x)$ over $F$ if $f(x)$ splits in $E$ but in no proper sub field of $E$

$(i)$ The above theorem must be true $\forall~~f(x)\in F[x]$ , but, there can exist $f(x)\in F[x]$ such that they split completely in $F$ ( and $F$ is clearly a sub field of $E$ ). Isn't this contradictory to the definition of a splitting field?

$(ii)$ The proof in my book is through induction. Is there a proof other than induction?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: To answer (i): if $f$ already splits in $F$, then its splitting field (over $F$) is $F$ itself. No contradiction. For (ii): why would you want to avoid induction?

Comment: For (ii) The abstract construction of splitting fields is naturally an inductive construction, since you need to start somewhere, and the only facts you can really get about a "random" polynomial is that it has a degree. Since you're talking about algebraic field extensions for which the definition is "looks like $F[x]/(p(x))$ done a lot of times$, I cannot imagine there's any non-inductive proof that is fundamentally different for an arbitrary field, and if so it must be awkward.

Comment: I get that. Thank you :-)

Comment: @Berci uhm, please do correct me if I am wrong but generally I find induction as non intuitive. I mean, say, a mathematician is working on a research problem. For him to actually prove a theorem, he must know the theorem in advance? Generally, are researchers able to know the result before they can prove it.

Comment: @VHP as a rule, one has a lot of examples before one guesses at a pattern for induction. They don't "know" but the idea is if the examples all seem to work and have some sort of order to them, they try induction to see if it will work if nothing else does. They don't usually "magically divine" things, though perhaps some people do.

Comment: interesting :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(i) If $f$ splits in $F$ then its splitting field over $F$ is just $E=F$, so no issue.

(ii) Quotient $F[x]/(f(x))$ by a maximal ideal, which necessarily exists, to get a field with an element, the image of $x$ in the quotient, satisfying the polynomial relation $f(x)=0$. (One can justifiably argue this only pushes induction back to Zorn's lemma, but that's just where I like it to be, not with degrees.)